How to access Synapse Lake Database externally
How can we query Azure Synapse Lake database within Azure SQL database? Is there a way to add Synapse lake database as an external data source in Azure SQL database
I have few tables present in Azure SQL database and few in Synapse Lake database.I want to access and modify both the tables within Azure SQL database. So is there a way to query Synapse Lake database by connecting to Azure SQL database

Azure SQL Databases are designed to be contained databases, generally, if you have the requirement to query other databases then you may have chosen the wrong tool. You might, however, be able to achieve it with an Elastic Query.

Alternatively, you can copy tables from lake database to sql database through synapse pipeline and modify the tables according to your requirement in azure SQL database instead of Elastic Query.

You can use elastic query option to achieve your requirement but according to this serverless SQL pool endpoints that you can use to query data in the Azure data lake database.  According to this Active directory authentication is not supported to create scoped credential, only sql server authentication is supported but As per this  MS doc

the SQL user exists only in serverless SQL pool and permissions are scoped to the objects in serverless SQL pool. Access to securable objects in other services (such as Azure Storage) can't be granted to SQL user directly since it only exists in scope of serverless SQL pool. The SQL user needs to use one of the  supported authorization types  to access the files.

So elastic query may not support to achieve your requirement. Alternatively, you can copy tables from lake database to Azure SQL database and modify the tables as follows:
Create linked service for synapse lake database with system assigned managed identity in synapse for source as configure below:

Create azure SQL database linked service for sink, select required table in source dataset and configure sink dataset as shown below:

Create new pipeline in synapse workspace use copy activity, select source and sink datasets and select Auto create table for table option in sink. debug the pipeline then required table will copy successfully to azure SQL database. If you have to copy multiple tables, follow this approach. Modify both azure SQL tables and lake database tables according to your requirement.
